# Count of consecutive repeated value only when repeated 3+ times

Tags: excel

My goal is to count and potentially conditionally format the occurrences when a certain number of days pass with 0 sales.
I am trying to return the number of times 0 is repeated consecutively 3 or more times. So for this example I would like to see the return value of 3.  So far I can't wrap my brain around how to do this, any ideas?

```
1
5
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
1
0
2
0
0
0
5
0
0
0
0
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is a beautiful answer to this type of problem which I believe came originally from @Barry Houdini. A variation on this https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/707800-counting-max-number-consecutive-blank-cells.html

Comment: Thanks Tom for sharing this solution, you were correct in that @Barry Houdini had solved this a while back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @Barry Houdini's method applied to this problem would give

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A21=0,ROW(A1:1A21)),IF(A1:A21>0,ROW(A1:A21)))>=3))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you wanted to make it more dynamic and exclude blanks you could use

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A100<>"",IF(A1:A100=0,ROW(A1:A100))),IF(A1:A100>0,ROW(A1:A100)))>=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you make a help column with a simple sum formula with a "window" of three rows (or whatever you need). Then you conditionally format all values which are 0 in that column. That should provide you with the information you are looking for.